# Products show case in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am implementing products show-case( not for a sale, but rather to show potential customers products what company can offer to them ) in Wordpress. I was thinking to install some plugin, however I am not that good in it, so I would require your help when it comes to that. Can you recommend me best possible plugin for it?

Answer (score 0):

a 'products show-case' without purchase, as in a gallery?

this might give you an idea of what to look for: [15 best gallery plugins](http://weppot.com/gallery-plugin-wordpress/)

Comment: Yes, without purchase, however I would like for each product to have it's own page.

Comment: I guess then all you are after is a wordpress e-commerce plugin found here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/free-ecommerce-wordpress-plugins/ i imagine any e-commerce plugin you go for will allow you to set an item not for sale but still show the product.